# Only first react component in map iteration is working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a component which displays an icon and when the icon is clicked it shows a menu. This component is placed in the first column of every row in an html table (using a map to iterate through an array of items to create the table). The problem I have is only the component in the first row of the table is showing the menu when clicked. The other icons are not doing anything when clicked.

For example, if tableItems is an array of 3 objects which when iterated over produces a table with 3 rows, the ActionMenu component in the first row displays a menu when clicked on. However the ActionMenu components on the 2nd and 3rd rows do nothing when they are clicked on. The click event isn't even fired.

I've tried placing the ActionMenu component 3 times outside the table in the same page as a test and they all worked so this problem seems to be with the component placed in the table. I'm not sure why or if it is because they are created inside a map iteration when creating the table.

If any one is able to help that would be much appreciated. I've included the function that does the iteration below and my code for the menu component.

```
const tableData = () => {
    return tableItems.map((item: any, index) => {
        const { id, value } = item;

        return (
            <div key={key} className="worklist-table-row">
              <div className="worklist-table-cell icon">
                  <ActionsMenu items={[
                      { id: "1", label: "menu choice 1"},
                      { id: "2", label: "menu choice 2"}
                  ]} />
              </div>
              ...
              other bits of code...
              ...
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

```
export default function ActionMenu(props: IContextMenu): JSX.Element {
  const { items } = props;
  const [showContextMenu, setShowContextMenu] = useState(false);

  const renderItems = () => {
    return items.map((item, index) => {
      return (
          <li key={index} className="context-menu-item">
              {isDivider ? (
                  <hr />
              ) : (
                  item.label
              )}
         </li>);
    });
  };

  return (
    <div id={id}>
      <Icon
        title="Action"
        icon="action"
        classNames="icon-action"
        onClick={() => {
          setShowContextMenu(!showContextMenu);
        }}
      />
      <nav className={cn('context-menu', { 'show-context': showContextMenu })}>
        <ul className="context-menu-group">{renderItems()}</ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of undefined values such as `id` and `isDivider` which need to be defined.

Code inside curly braces within JSX will be evaluated. `item.label` is already inside curly braces, so does not need to be wrapped in them again. (It will already be evaluated to get the label attribute of the item.)

Replace this:

```
{isDivider ? (
  <hr />
) : (
  {item.label}
)}
```

With this:

```
{isDivider ? (
  <hr />
) : (
  item.label
)}
```

Comment: Thanks georgegillams for the catch, unfortunately though that hasn't fixed my issue. The issue is that the ActionMenu component only works in the first row of the table, all other rows do not work. For example, if tableItems is an array of 3 objects which when iterated over produces a table with 3 rows, the ActionMenu component in the first row displays a menu when clicked on. However the ActionMenu components on the 2nd and 3rd rows do nothing when they are clicked on. The click event isn't even fired.

Comment: It's hard to debug any further with only the partial code provided. I don't know what `Icon` is, but I'd recommend replacing it with a `<button>` to see if that helps?
If you can share the full code to reproduce locally then I might be able to see something else.

Comment: Icon is just a custom component to display a user selected fontawsome icon. My guess is it's the ActionMenu setting a state variable combined with the map iteration that is causing the issue. However, I have no idea how to fix it if that is the issue.